# Why do I get a unicode encoding error in the middle of reading a file with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to make a program that reads every line that reads "hwlog read" in a txt file, and it runs fine, until the middle of the file, where it returns

```
(return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2856: character maps to undefined)
```

The part of the code that reads the program, is

```
with open(name, "r") as f:
    print("DEBUG")
    for line in f:
        if len(line.split()) == 5:
            if line.split()[-2] == "hwlog" and line.split()[-1] == "read":
                 input(line)
```

For the first few times, it works fine

```
lhsh BXP_1024 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_1024_1 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_1024_2 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_1025 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_1025_4 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_1025_5 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_2048 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_2049 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_2050 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_2051 hwlog read
lhsh BXP_2052 hwlog read
```

But after line 240070, it returns that error from before.
I tried re-converting the file into UTF-8, and even tried reinstalling python and tried on other devices, but it continues to happen. Why does this happen, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: There is most likely an invalid Unicode character in the file that you are reading from. You can try to either remove it manually or have the program ignore that line or that character.

Comment: If you are on linux, could you run this and post the output `cat /path/to/file | head -n 240071 |tail -n1 |xxd`

Comment: Non ASCII charcters are part of the data regardless.Telling one to "remove it manually or have the program remove it" won't fix things magically. Please, read the article I link in my answer - it is from 2003, but its 2019, and people are still not aware of "text is not bytes".

Comment: To read text, you have to have 1) the bytes and 2) the character encoding used to encode text to bytes so you can decode the bytes. It is all too common to not know the encoding of text. See if you can recover. There is no magic about it. Ask the sender. Ask the author.

Answer (score 1):

Your file has non-ASCII characters in it. Python 3 will open the file using a default encoding configured in your OS, if you put no explicit `encoding` argument when opening a text file - in this particular case, I can't tell you what encoding it is - it is not utf-8 or latin1, as one would give a different error message ("invalid starting byte") and the other would not fail with 0x81 .

Using latin1 will likely work to read your file without an UnicodeDecodeException - however, your data will still be broken - since "0x81" [is not a meaningful character in Latin1](https://codepoints.net/U+0081?lang=en) - so try to findout which is the text-encoding of your file first.

Ifit feels ambiguous when I talk about "discover what is the encoding from your file", I **strongly** suggest [you read this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), right now, before continuing any tasks.

Now, on trying a guess while "\x81" is not meaningful by itself in utf-8, it might be the second byte for an 'Á' char, which is encoded as b"\xc3\x81".

So, you might give it a try - just change your file-open line to:

```
with open(name, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

If it does not yield an error, then the file is in utf-8, as bytes wiht value > 127 must have a meaningful sequence that would not be met by chance.

Otherwise, just set the encoding as "latin-1" - it performs a transparent conversion from bytes to unicode code-points, but be aware that you are inserting [mojibake](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A%20mojubake&oq=define%3A%20mojubake&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.5729j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) into your data.